# How to dynamically insert insertText in CompletionItem in Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to dynamically insert insertText into the completionItem for a specific item when the user selects it from the TriggerSuggest items.

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const CompletionProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
    "smallbasic",
    {
      provideCompletionItems(
        document: vscode.TextDocument,
        position: vscode.Position
      ) {
        const textCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem("Text");
        const wordCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem("Word");
        return [TextsnippetCompletion, wordCompletion];
      },
    }
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(CompletionProvider);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

I tried using the resolveCompletionItem method in the CompletionItemProvider, but it only works after the user selects and the completion item is displayed, which didn't give me the desired result. Is there a way to achieve this?

---

**Edit**

[image: code Suggestion]

This is the situation where code suggestions occur. Typically, when providing a completionItem, I understand that insertText is specified along with it, like

```
const item = new completionItem("comcomc")
item.insertText("coco").
```

However, I want to dynamically assign insertText only when a user clicks on a specific completionItem item from the image I've uploaded.
When a specific completion item is clicked, I want to display its insertText value by receiving it from another class (A). Therefore, if we were to represent it in a timeline:

The user clicks on a specific completion item.
Information about the completion item is passed to class A, and the insertText value is retrieved.
The retrieved information is displayed in the vscode environment.

---

**Edit**

```
resolveCompletionItem(item: vscode.CompletionItem) {
       console.log("item : ", item);
       if (item) {
          // SmallBasic Snippet Generator
          const sbSnippetGenerator = new SbSnippetGenerator();
          const snippet = sbSnippetGenerator.getSnippet(item);
          console.log("성공");
          item.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString(snippet);
        }
        return item;
},
```

I'm not sure if this explanation is a perfect example, but I designed it to work like this. However, it worked fine when executing the completion item using keydown + Enter, but it didn't work when executing the completion item via mouse click

Comment: `dynamically insert insertText` explain better, you can show any text you want in the completion selection list

Comment: @rioV8 I've attached the sample code. If there's any part you don't understand, please let me know.